# How tableView or collectionview dequeue reusable works swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have ready many posts but I am not getting clear understanding about how it works    . As per my understanding for performance reason the same cell get reused but I have set of queries like

- During dequeue recycle how many cells are initially created in memory for any device like is there any specific number of cells are created eg N number of cells
- On scroll which particular cell gets reused
- Does static tableview supports dequeue

Comment: What do you mean by static cell?

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I have edited it. Means static prototype tableview

Comment: what's a static table view??

Comment: @Fattie I think he means the one that is not the list kind which you usually use for building a Settings view for apps. It's a storyboard thing i think, where almost always every cell is different and you can just design them by drag and drop.

Comment: that's weird   :)

Answer (score 1):

> During dequeue recycle how many cells are initially created in memory
>   for any device like is there any specific number of cells are created
>   eg N number of cell

- The required functions while creating table view contains tableView(_ tv: UITV, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int  & tableView(_ tv: UITV, numberOfSection section: Int) -> Int 
  both of them used to know how many sections and rows in section will appear in that tableview.

> On scroll which particular cell gets reused

- When a UITableViewCell scrolls off the screen, it gets put in a pool to be reused.
  The dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:) method grabs one out of that reuse pool.
  It is reusing a UITableViewCell with the given identifier if possible.
  Otherwise it is making a copy of the prototype in the storyboard.

> Does static tableview supports dequeue

- Static tableview is the opposite of dequeue reusable tableview because we already know the number of cells and how they look like . We can not reuse them.